# pyspark on databricks, using multiple source files with git

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm working with databricks and try to find a good setup for my project. Basically I have to process many files and therefore I wrote quite a bit of python code. I'm now faced with the problem to run this code on a spark cluster such that my source code files are on the respective nodes as well. My approach so far (it even works) is to call a map on an rdd which then runs the parse_file function for each element of the rdd. Is there a better approach, such I don't have to clone every time the whole git?

```
def parse_file(filename, string):
  os.system("rm -rf source_code_folder")
  os.system("git clone https://user:password@dev.azure.com/company/project/_git/repo source_code_folder")
  sys.path.append(os.path.join(subprocess.getoutput("pwd"),"source_code_folder/"))
  from my_module1.whatever import my_function
  from my_module2.whatever import some_other_function
  result = (my_function(string), some_other_function(string))
  return result

my_rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("abfss://raw@storage_account.dfs.core.windows.net/files/*.txt")
processed_rdd = my_rdd(lambda x: (x[0], parse_file(x[0],x[1])))
```

Thanks!